# Resize absolute panel and text inside it on different screens (Desktop, Laptop, Mobile)

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, screen

My shiny application has different **absolute panels**, but their appearance is different on different screens.  In particular, I noticed that the size of the panel and the text inside it, usually present inside `h()` tags) are always the same, while some widget (as actionButtons) are automatically resized. Here is a minimal reproducible example with an `absolutePanel` that is supposed to appear in the middle of the screen:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  absolutePanel(id = "initial_panel",
                fixed = TRUE,
                top = 0,
                left = 0,
                bottom = 0,
                right = 0,
                width = 900,
                height = 450,
                style = "background-color: white;
                         opacity: 0.85;
                         padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
                         margin: auto;
                         border-radius: 5pt;
                         box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 6pt 0px rgba(61,59,61,0.48);
                         padding-bottom: 2mm;
                         padding-top: 1mm;",

                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         h1(strong("Welcome!"))
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         h3("Some more text")
                  )
                ),

                br(),

                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         actionButton(inputId = "explore",
                                      label = icon(name = "times",
                                                   class = "fa-2x",
                                                   lib = "font-awesome")
                         )
                  )
                )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If from my desktop I switch to the laptop, this panel takes almost the 60% of the screen size (so it's too big). Any suggestion on how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `vw` and `vh` CSS units, e.g. `width = "50vw"` and `height = "50vh"`, which respectively means 50% of the viewport width and 50% of the viewport height.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but where should I put these css arguments? Inside the "style" of the absolute panel and also for the h1 and h3 tags?

Comment: No. Replace `width=900` and `height=450`.

Comment: What you suggested works perfectly for the absolutePanel, but not for the text. See this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/WGRp6bv.png). The text goes outside of the window and doesn't scale, but the action button inside do, but since the text is too large the action button are pushed outside of the panel.

Comment: Indeed. You can use the `vh` CSS unit in `font-size`. Instead of using `h1`, you can do for example `tags$p(strong("Welcome!"), style = "font-size: 3vh;")`. And instead of `h3`, do `tags$p("Some more text", style = "font-size: 1vh;")`. Say me if it works.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, thanks a lot. Can we move it as answer? I think it could be really useful. One last thing, can I apply the same concept to the blank lines that I can obtain through tags$br()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the width with the `vw` CSS unit and the height with the `vh` CSS unit. These units are percentages of the viewport width and the viewport height respectively.  For example, `width = "50vw"` for 50% of the viewport width. Note that this also scales when the window is resized.

`h1` and `h3` have a fixed size. Instead, you can use a `p` tag and specify its CSS property `font-size` in `vh` units.

`br` is a line break, its height is the one of `line-height`. Instead of using a `br()`, you can use an empty `div` with the CSS property `height` given in `vh` units: `div(style = "height: 2vh;")`.

```
  absolutePanel(id = "initial_panel",
                fixed = TRUE,
                top = 0,
                left = 0,
                bottom = 0,
                right = 0,
                width = "50vw",
                height = "50vh",
                style = "background-color: white;
                         opacity: 0.85;
                         padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
                         margin: auto;
                         border-radius: 5pt;
                         box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 6pt 0px rgba(61,59,61,0.48);
                         padding-bottom: 2mm;
                         padding-top: 1mm;",

                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p(strong("Welcome!"), style = "font-size: 3vh;")
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p("Some more text", style = "font-size: 1vh;")
                  )
                ),

                div(style = "height: 2vh;"),

                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         actionButton(inputId = "explore",
                                      label = icon(name = "times",
                                                   class = "fa-2x",
                                                   lib = "font-awesome")
                         )
                  )
                )
  )
```

Comment: Stéphan may I ask you your opinion about another small issue? With your solution I noticed that the panel and the text inside it resize correctly when the aspect ratio of the window is maintained. When I modify the shape of the window to, for example, a square (or for example when you use the app through mobile) the text doesn't resize and push other element outside of the panel. Please check an example [here](https://i.imgur.com/DwkhyZb.png). Should I create another question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nd091680 Hmmm.. honestly I don't know :-(. You could open a new question but I don't think I would be the one who can help here.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I will open a new issue.