# Resize text and icons inside absolute panel of shiny app when aspect ratio of browsers window is not 16:9

Tags: css, r, browser, shiny, window

I have a shiny app with an absolute panel that appears in the middle of the screen when the application starts. In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880757/resize-absolute-panel-and-text-inside-it-on-different-screens-desktop-laptop), thanks to the help of [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent), I managed to resize the absolute panel and the text inside it by using, for every element of my UI, the CSS units for width and height related to the viewport (respectively "vw" and "vh") and not the common "px".

**This works perfectly when the aspect ratio of the screen remains almost the same** (around 16:9), but when the window changes dimensions (for example is taller than wide) the panel resizes but not the text, with the consequence that it pushes other elements of the UI outside the absolute panel. Please check an example of this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abekk.jpg).

Below there's a minimal reproducible example. Please try to resize the browser window to check this problem.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  absolutePanel(id = "initial_panel",
                fixed = TRUE,
                top = 0,
                left = 0,
                bottom = 0,
                right = 0,
                width = "34vw",
                height = "31.5vh",
                style = "background-color: white;
                         opacity: 0.85;
                         padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
                         margin: auto;
                         border-radius: 5pt;
                         box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 6pt 0px rgba(61,59,61,0.48);
                         padding-bottom: 2mm;
                         padding-top: 1mm;",

                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 1
                  ),
                  column(width = 10,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p(strong("AAAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA"),
                                style = "font-size: 2.8vh;")
                  ),
                  column(width = 1,
                         align = "right",
                         actionButton(inputId = "close_initial_panel",
                                      label = icon(name = "times",
                                                   lib = "font-awesome"),
                                      style = "font-size: 1.5vh;
                                                 padding: 0vh 0vh 0vh 0vh;
                                                 margin-top: -9px;
                                                 margin-right: -14px;
                                                 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);")
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 12,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p("BBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB",
                                style = "font-size: 1.9vh;")
                  )
                ),

  div(style = "height: 5.7vh;"),

                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 4,
                         align = "center",
                         actionButton(inputId = "explore_amr_map",
                                      label = img(src = "world_icon.png",
                                                  width = "96%",
                                                  height = "95%",
                                                  align = "center"))
                  ),
                  column(width = 4,
                         align = "center",
                         actionButton(inputId = "fill_form2",
                                      label = img(src = "location-map_icon2.png",
                                                  height = "45%",
                                                  width = "45%",
                                                  align = "center"))
                  ),
                  column(width = 4,
                         align = "center",
                         NEWdownloadButton(outputId = "download_RESBANK2",
                                           label = img(src = "download_icon.png",
                                                       height = "54%",
                                                       width = "54%",
                                                       align = "center"))
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 4,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p(strong("CCC CC CCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCC"),
                                style = "font-size: 1.3vh;")

                  ),
                  column(width = 4,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p(strong("EEEEE EEEEE EEEE EEEE"),
                                style = "font-size: 1.3vh;"),
                  ),
                  column(width = 4,
                         align = "center",
                         tags$p(strong("FFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFF"),
                                style = "font-size: 1.3vh;"),
                  )
                )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This may represent a problem on smartphone, for example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's also the unit `vmin` which is the min of `vh` and `vw`. I don't think it would solve the issue, but this could be better, perhaps.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent, with the @nd091680 code example, `vmin` works in most of the cases at least in my not so throughful tests, so probably it is really the solution for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, in which cases of my example code should I use `vmin`?

Comment: @MalditoBarbudo should I replace every `vw` and `vh` inside my code with `vmin`, or do I have to replace it just for the text?

Comment: Just for the text if you want the text to also get smaller when the width is less than the height. If you want that beahviour also for other elements (like the absolute panel...) then also there. Just play with it until you get confortable and understand what vh, vw and vmin do.

Comment: Ok, I used vmin on every text inside the panel and the situation improved. The last problem that I have is that an element inside my fluidRow (the "x" symbol) go on the new line, even though I just used 12 columns and not more. See the image attached [here](https://i.imgur.com/fgpVPQU.png) please. Thanks a lot for you help.